# Bootstrap Typeahead Not Registering in AngularJS ng-view

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to get Twitter Bootstrap's Typeahead feature working inside of an AngularJS ng-view, but the Javascript call is not registering the service.

I am aware of AngularJS implementations of Bootstrap, but I have to use "raw" Bootstrap at the moment.

- AngularUI Bootstrap: does not fire an 'updater' event, and `$watch` causes odd side effects.

  - `ng-change` fires when typing & on a typeahead selection.  I only want a typeahead selection.
  - `$watch` is not firing on a typeahead selection and attempts to find the right place to insert `$digest` have failed.
- AngularStrap: fires a single `typeahead-updated` event but does not distinguish where it came from in the case of multiple typeaheads (which I have).

If I set up a "HTML only" typeahead, it works:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox_EMPID" class="span6" placeholder="8675309" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source='["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona"'>
```

But if I set it up to initialize via Javascript, the Typeahead no longer appears.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox_EMPID" class="span6" placeholder="8675309" data-provide="typeahead">
```

Javascript:

```
$('#textbox_EMPID').typeahead({
  minLength: 3,
  source: function (query, process) 
  {
    console.log("checking");
    // snipped $.get() call
  },
});
```

If I call other jQuery actions on field, it does work.  For example, the following will hide the field when placed in the same `<script>` block:

```
$('textbox_EMPID').hide();
```

Calling the below does succeed, indicating that the `typeahead` function is available:

```
if(jQuery().typeahead) { alert("yes"); }
```

But the "source" section of the `typeahead` is never called.  I left out the guts of a `$.get()` request, because the `console.log()` never appears either.

I moved this code over from a non-AngularJS page that I wrote, where it is working just fine.  It is unclear to me what I am missing that would cause this to break inside an `ng-view`.

Comment: The contents of an `ng-view` are loaded in asynchronously. Is it possible that your JavaScript is running when the page first loads, before the `ng-view` contents appear? If you put the JavaScript inside a directive and attach the directive to your text field, you should be good to go. Mixing traditional "global" jQuery methodology and Angular is a recipe for frustration.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "AngularUI Bootstrap: does not fire an 'updater' event, and $watch causes odd side effects"? What are the  "odd side effects"? Did you try using `ng-change` to capture selection? What is your use-case?

Comment: @BrandonTilley, indeed mixing is a recipe for frustration! :)  The HTML & Javascript are in the same file, so they are loaded at the same time; calling other actions on the field seems to work, just not the typeahead.  I'll try the directive route.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource, I gave `ng-change` a try but it fires too frequently.  I've updated my question with more details.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey notification on match select would be trivial to add in http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ so if you've got a good use-case feel free to raise an issue in https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource, done.  https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/433.  I've looked through the code some, I might try my hand at a hack example in a fork.