# Typeahead not recognized inside ng-view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I have two files. One is an index.html, which essentially is the frame for my website, and the other a main.html which holds the template for my homepage. I have the following code right before all my scripts are imported.

```
   <div class="container">
        <div class="well" ng-view=""></div>

        <div class="footer">
            <p translate="footer">Well hello there Mr. Footer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

All my typeahead and controllers are imported in my scripts. This defaults to pulling my main.html because of the routed controller. The issue is that when I put the following code into my index.html, the typeahead works fine, but as as soon as I move it into my main.html it stops working. All of my javascript is being ran from files, so it shouldn't be a conflict of which loads first... Thoughts?

```
        <div ng-controller="employeeController">
            <table>
                <center>
                    <div id="the-basics">
                        <input type="text" 
                            ng-model="text" 
                            ng-change="get(text, 'name')"
                            class="typeahead" 
                            id="search" 
                            placeholder="Search Employees..."/> 
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" ng-click="get(text, 'name')">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>
                </center>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Here is a somewhat similar question that was never answered:
[Bootstrap Typeahead Not Registering in AngularJS ng-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526316/bootstrap-typeahead-not-registering-in-angularjs-ng-view)

Comment: Further investigation showed me that the code above has to be put in my index file before my script imports in order for it to work... It seems like ng-view may be getting loaded after the scripts after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by putting another script import for the controllers directly into the main.html.